# "invalid_grant" error in google authentication only for iOS 16 devices

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0, bad-request, ios16

I am using the https://github.com/p2/OAuth2 library to upload videos on youtube, till the iOS 16 app functionality is working fine, but for iOS 16 devices getting an "invalid_grant"(Bad Request) error. The same code is working for the iOS 15.1 version.

Code setup:

```
self.oauth2 = OAuth2CodeGrant(settings: [
"client_id": "XXXXX",
"authorize_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
"token_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
"redirect_uris": ["XXXX"],
"scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload",
"use_keychain": true,
"keychain_access_mode": kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock,
"keychain_account_for_tokens": "XXXXXX",
] as OAuth2JSON)

self.oauth2.authorize { result, error in
print("error",error?.localizedDescription) // The operation couldn’t be completed. (Base.OAuth2Error error 13.)
}
```

Testing version:
https://github.com/p2/OAuth2: Master branch's latest version,
Realdevices: iPhone 11 (iOS16) - not working, iphone 11(iOS 15.1) - working.